# Pass data to child action's view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, child-actions

I have multiple views which call the same child action, which renders a view.
Depending on which view calls the child action, I want to display a *different message in the childview*. But since I don't need this view inside the child action's controller method, I feel passing it along as a **controller parameter** is not a very nice solution.

I tried **ViewData**, which doesn't work -- it gets emptied for the child call
I currently use **TempData**, which works but not very nice, since it uses session for no real reason

**Is there any other option than these three?**
(it should also work in MVC2, please)

Comment: I have the same problem... anything new on this?